# Can't find preferences tab to adjust and customize grids

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, grids

I was just going through this tutorial **[HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MSAGUhzA-90)** , and this guy adjusts his grids, by going to preferences, see the screenshot that I grabbed from the video:

[image: settings image]

Now I have the following Photoshop configuration:

```
Adobe Photoshop Version: 13.0 (13.0 20120315.r.428 2012/03/15:21:00:00) x64
Operating System: Windows 7 64-bit
Version: 6.1 Service Pack 1
System architecture: Intel CPU Family:6, Model:5, Stepping:5 with MMX, SSE Integer, SSE FP, SSE2, SSE3, SSE4.1, SSE4.2, HyperThreading
Physical processor count: 2
Logical processor count: 4
Processor speed: 2527 MHz
Built-in memory: 3894 MB
Free memory: 858 MB
Memory available to Photoshop: 3319 MB
Memory used by Photoshop: 60 %
Image tile size: 128K
Image cache levels: 4
OpenGL Drawing: Enabled.
OpenGL Drawing Mode: Basic
OpenGL Allow Normal Mode: True.
OpenGL Allow Advanced Mode: True.
OpenGL Allow Old GPUs: Not Detected.
Video Card Vendor: Intel
Video Card Renderer: Intel(R) HD Graphics
Display: 1
Display Bounds:=  top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 768, right: 1366 
Video Card Number: 1
Video Card: Intel(R) HD Graphics
OpenCL Unavailable
Driver Version: 8.15.10.2430
Driver Date: 20110626000000.000000-000
Video Card Driver: igdumd64.dll,igd10umd64.dll,igdumdx32,igd10umd32
Video Mode: 1366 x 768 x 4294967296 colors
Video Card Caption: Intel(R) HD Graphics
Video Card Memory: 1723 MB
Video Rect Texture Size: 8192
Serial number: 92628701192123445467
Application folder: C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS6 (64 Bit)\
Temporary file path: C:\Users\Silambu\AppData\Local\Temp\
Photoshop scratch has async I/O enabled
Scratch volume(s):
  Startup, 78.0G, 4.22G free
Required Plug-ins folder: C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS6 (64 Bit)\Required\
Primary Plug-ins folder: C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS6 (64 Bit)\Plug-ins\
Additional Plug-ins folder: not set

Installed components:
   A3DLIBS.dll   A3DLIB Dynamic Link Library   9.2.0.112   
   ACE.dll   ACE 2012/01/18-15:07:40   66.492997   66.492997
   adbeape.dll   Adobe APE 2012/01/25-10:04:55   66.1025012   66.1025012
   AdobeLinguistic.dll   Adobe Linguisitc Library   6.0.0   
   AdobeOwl.dll   Adobe Owl 2012/02/09-16:00:02   4.0.93   66.496052
   AdobePDFL.dll   PDFL 2011/12/12-16:12:37   66.419471   66.419471
   AdobePIP.dll   Adobe Product Improvement Program   6.0.0.1654   
   AdobeXMP.dll   Adobe XMP Core 2012/02/06-14:56:27   66.145661   66.145661
   AdobeXMPFiles.dll   Adobe XMP Files 2012/02/06-14:56:27   66.145661   66.145661
   AdobeXMPScript.dll   Adobe XMP Script 2012/02/06-14:56:27   66.145661   66.145661
   adobe_caps.dll   Adobe CAPS   6,0,29,0   
   AGM.dll   AGM 2012/01/18-15:07:40   66.492997   66.492997
   ahclient.dll    AdobeHelp Dynamic Link Library   1,7,0,56   
   aif_core.dll   AIF   3.0   62.490293
   aif_ocl.dll   AIF   3.0   62.490293
   aif_ogl.dll   AIF   3.0   62.490293
   amtlib.dll   AMTLib (64 Bit)   6.0.0.75 (BuildVersion: 6.0; BuildDate: Mon Jan 16 2012 18:00:00)   1.000000
   ARE.dll   ARE 2012/01/18-15:07:40   66.492997   66.492997
   AXE8SharedExpat.dll   AXE8SharedExpat 2011/12/16-15:10:49   66.26830   66.26830
   AXEDOMCore.dll   AXEDOMCore 2011/12/16-15:10:49   66.26830   66.26830
   Bib.dll   BIB 2012/01/18-15:07:40   66.492997   66.492997
   BIBUtils.dll   BIBUtils 2012/01/18-15:07:40   66.492997   66.492997
   boost_date_time.dll   DVA Product   6.0.0   
   boost_signals.dll   DVA Product   6.0.0   
   boost_system.dll   DVA Product   6.0.0   
   boost_threads.dll   DVA Product   6.0.0   
   cg.dll   NVIDIA Cg Runtime   3.0.00007   
   cgGL.dll   NVIDIA Cg Runtime   3.0.00007   
   CIT.dll   Adobe CIT   2.0.5.19287   2.0.5.19287
   CoolType.dll   CoolType 2012/01/18-15:07:40   66.492997   66.492997
   data_flow.dll   AIF   3.0   62.490293
   dvaaudiodevice.dll   DVA Product   6.0.0   
   dvacore.dll   DVA Product   6.0.0   
   dvamarshal.dll   DVA Product   6.0.0   
   dvamediatypes.dll   DVA Product   6.0.0   
   dvaplayer.dll   DVA Product   6.0.0   
   dvatransport.dll   DVA Product   6.0.0   
   dvaunittesting.dll   DVA Product   6.0.0   
   dynamiclink.dll   DVA Product   6.0.0   
   ExtendScript.dll   ExtendScript 2011/12/14-15:08:46   66.490082   66.490082
   FileInfo.dll   Adobe XMP FileInfo 2012/01/17-15:11:19   66.145433   66.145433
   filter_graph.dll   AIF   3.0   62.490293
   hydra_filters.dll   AIF   3.0   62.490293
   icucnv40.dll   International Components for Unicode 2011/11/15-16:30:22    Build gtlib_3.0.16615   
   icudt40.dll   International Components for Unicode 2011/11/15-16:30:22    Build gtlib_3.0.16615   
   image_compiler.dll   AIF   3.0   62.490293
   image_flow.dll   AIF   3.0   62.490293
   image_runtime.dll   AIF   3.0   62.490293
   JP2KLib.dll   JP2KLib 2011/12/12-16:12:37   66.236923   66.236923
   libifcoremd.dll   Intel(r) Visual Fortran Compiler   10.0 (Update A)   
   libmmd.dll   Intel(r) C Compiler, Intel(r) C++ Compiler, Intel(r) Fortran Compiler   10.0   
   LogSession.dll   LogSession   2.1.2.1640   
   mediacoreif.dll   DVA Product   6.0.0   
   MPS.dll   MPS 2012/02/03-10:33:13   66.495174   66.495174
   msvcm80.dll   Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2005   8.00.50727.6195   
   msvcm90.dll   Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2008   9.00.30729.1   
   msvcp100.dll   Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2010   10.00.40219.1   
   msvcp80.dll   Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2005   8.00.50727.6195   
   msvcp90.dll   Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2008   9.00.30729.1   
   msvcr100.dll   Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2010   10.00.40219.1   
   msvcr80.dll   Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2005   8.00.50727.6195   
   msvcr90.dll   Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2008   9.00.30729.1   
   pdfsettings.dll   Adobe PDFSettings   1.04   
   Photoshop.dll   Adobe Photoshop CS6   CS6   
   Plugin.dll   Adobe Photoshop CS6   CS6   
   PlugPlug.dll   Adobe(R) CSXS PlugPlug Standard Dll (64 bit)   3.0.0.383   
   PSArt.dll   Adobe Photoshop CS6   CS6   
   PSViews.dll   Adobe Photoshop CS6   CS6   
   SCCore.dll   ScCore 2011/12/14-15:08:46   66.490082   66.490082
   ScriptUIFlex.dll   ScriptUIFlex 2011/12/14-15:08:46   66.490082   66.490082
   tbb.dll   Intel(R) Threading Building Blocks for Windows   3, 0, 2010, 0406   
   tbbmalloc.dll   Intel(R) Threading Building Blocks for Windows   3, 0, 2010, 0406   
   TfFontMgr.dll   FontMgr   9.3.0.113   
   TfKernel.dll   Kernel   9.3.0.113   
   TFKGEOM.dll   Kernel Geom   9.3.0.113   
   TFUGEOM.dll   Adobe, UGeom©   9.3.0.113   
   updaternotifications.dll   Adobe Updater Notifications Library   6.0.0.24 (BuildVersion: 1.0; BuildDate: BUILDDATETIME)   6.0.0.24
   WRServices.dll   WRServices Friday January 27 2012 13:22:12   Build 0.17112   0.17112
   wu3d.dll   U3D Writer   9.3.0.113   


Required plug-ins:

   Accented Edges 13.0
   Adaptive Wide Angle 13.0
   ADM 3.11x01
   Angled Strokes 13.0
   Average 13.0 (13.0 20120315.r.428 2012/03/15:21:00:00)
   Bas Relief 13.0
   BMP 13.0
   Camera Raw 8.3
   Camera Raw Filter 8.3
   Chalk & Charcoal 13.0
   Charcoal 13.0
   Chrome 13.0
   Cineon 13.0 (13.0 20120315.r.428 2012/03/15:21:00:00)
   Clouds 13.0 (13.0 20120315.r.428 2012/03/15:21:00:00)
   Collada 13.0 (13.0 20120315.r.428 2012/03/15:21:00:00)
   Color Halftone 13.0
   Colored Pencil 13.0
   CompuServe GIF 13.0
   Conté Crayon 13.0
   Craquelure 13.0
   Crop and Straighten Photos 13.0 (13.0 20120315.r.428 2012/03/15:21:00:00)
   Crop and Straighten Photos Filter 13.0
   Crosshatch 13.0
   Crystallize 13.0
   Cutout 13.0
   Dark Strokes 13.0
   De-Interlace 13.0
   Difference Clouds 13.0 (13.0 20120315.r.428 2012/03/15:21:00:00)
   Diffuse Glow 13.0
   Displace 13.0
   Dry Brush 13.0
   Eazel Acquire 13.0 (13.0 20120315.r.428 2012/03/15:21:00:00)
   Embed Watermark 4.0
   Extrude 13.0
   FastCore Routines 13.0 (13.0 20120315.r.428 2012/03/15:21:00:00)
   Fibers 13.0
   Film Grain 13.0
   Filter Gallery 13.0
   Fresco 13.0
   Glass 13.0
   Glowing Edges 13.0
   Grain 13.0
   Graphic Pen 13.0
   Halftone Pattern 13.0
   HDRMergeUI 13.0
   IFF Format 13.0
   Ink Outlines 13.0
   JPEG 2000 13.0
   Lens Blur 13.0
   Lens Correction 13.0
   Lens Flare 13.0
   Liquify 13.0
   Matlab Operation 13.0 (13.0 20120315.r.428 2012/03/15:21:00:00)
   Measurement Core 13.0 (13.0 20120315.r.428 2012/03/15:21:00:00)
   Mezzotint 13.0
   MMXCore Routines 13.0 (13.0 20120315.r.428 2012/03/15:21:00:00)
   Mosaic Tiles 13.0
   Multiprocessor Support 13.0 (13.0 20120315.r.428 2012/03/15:21:00:00)
   Neon Glow 13.0
   Note Paper 13.0
   NTSC Colors 13.0 (13.0 20120315.r.428 2012/03/15:21:00:00)
   Ocean Ripple 13.0
   Oil Paint 13.0
   OpenEXR 13.0
   Paint Daubs 13.0
   Palette Knife 13.0
   Patchwork 13.0
   Paths to Illustrator 13.0
   PCX 13.0 (13.0 20120315.r.428 2012/03/15:21:00:00)
   Photocopy 13.0
   Photoshop 3D Engine 13.0 (13.0 20120315.r.428 2012/03/15:21:00:00)
   Picture Package Filter 13.0 (13.0 20120315.r.428 2012/03/15:21:00:00)
   Pinch 13.0
   Pixar 13.0 (13.0 20120315.r.428 2012/03/15:21:00:00)
   Plaster 13.0
   Plastic Wrap 13.0
   PNG 13.0
   Pointillize 13.0
   Polar Coordinates 13.0
   Portable Bit Map 13.0 (13.0 20120315.r.428 2012/03/15:21:00:00)
   Poster Edges 13.0
   Radial Blur 13.0
   Radiance 13.0 (13.0 20120315.r.428 2012/03/15:21:00:00)
   Read Watermark 4.0
   Reticulation 13.0
   Ripple 13.0
   Rough Pastels 13.0
   Save for Web 13.0
   ScriptingSupport 13.0
   Shear 13.0
   Smart Blur 13.0
   Smudge Stick 13.0
   Solarize 13.0 (13.0 20120315.r.428 2012/03/15:21:00:00)
   Spatter 13.0
   Spherize 13.0
   Sponge 13.0
   Sprayed Strokes 13.0
   Stained Glass 13.0
   Stamp 13.0
   Sumi-e 13.0
   Targa 13.0
   Texturizer 13.0
   Tiles 13.0
   Torn Edges 13.0
   Twirl 13.0
   Underpainting 13.0
   Vanishing Point 13.0
   Variations 13.0 (13.0 20120315.r.428 2012/03/15:21:00:00)
   Water Paper 13.0
   Watercolor 13.0
   Wave 13.0
   WIA Support 13.0 (13.0 20120315.r.428 2012/03/15:21:00:00)
   Wind 13.0
   Wireless Bitmap 13.0 (13.0 20120315.r.428 2012/03/15:21:00:00)
   ZigZag 13.0

Optional and third party plug-ins: NONE

Plug-ins that failed to load: NONE
Flash:
   Mini Bridge
   Kuler
Installed TWAIN devices: NONE
```

But I don't have the preferences tab in my menu, so is the preferences tab available in my version of Photoshop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find it under "Edit/Preferences/Guides, Grids & Slices" The starting point is the "Edit" menu at the top.